# Remote connection in sql connects one way

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, firewall, remote-access, remote-connection

I have two sql instances:
instance-1 on server-A
instance-2 on server-R.

Both instances are on different domains. I can connect remotely to instance-1 from server-R successfully but I am unable to connect to instance-2 from server-A.

When I attempt the connection it throws error-26.  I have allowed ports 1433,1434 through the firewalls and SQL Browser service is running on both servers.

What are some possible things I have overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

There's an article about this on the MSDN blogs.
[Click here to read: Error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx)

Suggestions from the article:

> The client stack could not receive SSRP response UDP packet from SQL
>   Browser. It's easy to isolate the issue. Here are the steps:
>
> 1) Make sure your server name is correct, e.g., no typo on the name.
>
> 2) Make sure your instance name is correct and there is actually such
>   an instance on your target machine. [Update: Some application converts
>   `\\ to \.` If you are not sure about your application, please try both
>   `Server\Instance and Server\\Instance` in your connection string]
>
> 3) Make sure the server machine is reachable, e.g, DNS can be resolve
>   correctly, you are able to ping the server (not always true).
>
> 4) Make sure SQL Browser service is running on the server.
>
> 5) If firewall is enabled on the server, you need to put
>   sqlbrowser.exe and/or UDP port 1434 into exception.

Based on what you tried already, then maybe it could be a name typo, DNS or try both `Server\Instance and Server\\Instance` in your connection string.

The MSDN article have other notes to review as well.

Comment: servers are reachable and pinging. i have added mentioned ports in firewall but still i am unable to connect from server-A to instance-2

Comment: Are you attempting to connect via a script or SQL Management Studio or anther application? If you made any config changes, then try a server restart. A quick debug option is to try a different transaction with the servers and see how they respond. So, if you're into scripting for example, try connect with an asp.net script or VB/C# app (in debug mode) and see the error. Or try a connection to another service on the box like IIS, FTP, etc.

Comment: I am using **SQL Management Studio**. Even Server restart didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Are you still obtaining error-26? Did you check Windows Event Viewer... there might be some log entries that could help. Do you see an attempt to connect to SQL Server at the times you tried?

Answer (score -1):

About error 26 following link may help you probably:

http://www.codecandle.com/Articles/102/SQL/Administration/error-26-Error-Locating-Server-Instance-Specified%29-%28Microsoft-SQL-Server-Error-1%29/codedetail.aspx

Issue's source is high probability due to instance 2, not server A.

If you opened sqlbrowser port, also check if it actually listens via command prompt.